# Javascript is blocked. ICEfaces cannot run on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, icefaces

i've been development some web app on Icefaces 1.7.2 and it's impossible to me run my app on chrome. When i click some icefaces element like link or button and that's trigger some javascript (ajax) my google chrome it's blocking the request or javascrit and only shows this message

"Javascript is blocked. ICEfaces cannot run on chrome "

can anybody helpme ?

my web app it's www.flygonet.com and is under development.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to take it up with them. Their site [claims](http://www.icefaces.org/main/ajax-java/platforms.iface) they support Google Chrome 1.x. Chrome is on version 8 right now, so they seem to be pretty far behind the curve.

Since you're using their software, you're at the mercy of what they will support.

Comment: thanks, but the "showcase components" that they have on internet at http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface runs perfectly on chrome (i've try several versions) ... i don't know what's going bad :(

Comment: Perhaps your version is too old? They seem to have some newer releases than the one that you're using.